# How can I flip distributivness of a union in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In the code below what `SomeMagic` type needs to be to reverse distrubutivness of `Y`?

```
type X<A> = { value: A };
type Y = X<number> | X<string>;
type Z = SomeMagic<Y>;  // <-- what SomeMagic should be to get Z of X<number | string>?
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the type of `Y.value` and use it as parameter for `X`:

```
type X<A> = { value: A };
type Y = X<number> | X<string>;
type Z = X<Y['value']>;
```

as a result:

```
type Z = {
  value: string | number;
};
```

Comment: Or If `X` is more complex you can use a conditional type to extract `A`: `type GetA<T extends X<any>> = T extends X<infer U> ? U : never;`